# How can I position my kivy app window in the right bottom corner

Tags: python, kivy

I have a kivy desktop app and want to start it in the corner at the right.
Currently, i can only apply the position from the left, top...

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics','position','custom')
Config.set('graphics','resizable',0)
Config.set('graphics','left',20)
Config.set('graphics','top',50)
Config.write()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that using the `left` and `top` properties are the only way to position an app. If that is true, then you must get the size of the device screen, and use that to calculate the the `top` and `left`. However, getting the size of the device screen is difficult in python/kivy. You can get an approximation by maximizing the kivy window and using its size. Here is some code that follows this approach:

```
def do_maximize(self, dt):
    self.app_size = Window.size
    Window.maximize()
    Clock.schedule_once(self.adjust_window)

def adjust_window(self, dt):
    window_size = Window.size
    top = Window.top
    left = Window.left
    Window.restore()
    Window.top = window_size[1] - self.app_size[1] + top
    Window.left = window_size[0] - self.app_size[0] + left
```

And calling:

```
    Clock.schedule_once(self.do_maximize)
```

from the `App.build()` method should approximate what you want.

A more accurate, but more complex approach would be to use `subprocess` to run a command to capture the device size (something like `xdpyinfo` on Linux) and parse the output to get the size.

Answer (score 0):

thank you @John Anderson your solution worked, i had only to apply one line for my needs.

```
def do_maximize(self, dt):
    self.app_size = Window.size
    Window.maximize()
    Clock.schedule_once(self.adjust_window)

def adjust_window(self, dt):
    window_size = Window.size
    top = Window.top - 50
    left = Window.left
    Window.restore()
    Window.size = (400, 200) # new (desired window size)
    self.app_size = Window.size
    Window.top = window_size[1] - self.app_size[1] + top
    Window.left = window_size[0] - self.app_size[0] + left
```